# Server Side JavaScript Data retrieval from Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am loading records from a Data Extension, which would have close to 1 Million records.

I am using a field called IsProcessed and after processing the rows for each batch marking the IsProcessed to TRUE so they are not fetched in the next retrieve.

My question is around the function I am using.

I see 2 server-side Javascript function and the only difference I see is the batch size, one is 2000 and the other is 2500. If my filtering criteria is satisfied by both, is there any specific reason to chose one over the another.
Apologies if I am missing something obvious.

Function 1:

```
var moredata = deEmail.Rows.Retrieve(filterlogic);
```

Function 2:

```
var dataRows = Platform.Function.LookupRows('DE_Name',['Field1','IsProcessed'],['Value','FALSE']);
```

Thanks for helping.

Regards,Monomit

Answer (score 0):

The one difference is the output type.

While `dataRows` outputs a **rowset**, the `Rows.Retrieve()` gives out **JSON** output (array of objects in JSON format).